# Angular Dynamic Component Issue

Tags: javascript, angular

I make a dynamic component in one of my components and it was made and here it's in the html I place it in the (ng-template) :

```
<div type="text" class="form-control" contenteditable="true" name="phrase" (input)="triggerChange($event)">
          <ng-container #container></ng-container>
      </div>
```

Code of triggerChange :

```
  triggerChange(event) {
    let newText = event.target.innerText;
    this.updateLineAndParentLineAndCreateComponent(newText);
  }
```

Which made what the function says literally update the line with the new text and update the parent component with this changes and also make the on the fly component

Code for create Component :

```
compileTemplate(line: any) {
    // console.log(line[4]);
    let metadata = {
      selector: `runtime-component-sample`,
      template: line[4]
    };
    let factory = this.createComponentFactorySync(this.compiler, metadata);


    if (this.componentRef) {
      this.componentRef.destroy();
      this.componentRef = null;
    }

    this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
    let instance = <DynamicComponent>this.componentRef.instance;
    instance.line = line;
    instance.selectPhrase.subscribe(this.selectPhrase.bind(this));
  }

  private createComponentFactorySync(compiler: Compiler, metadata: Component, componentClass?: any): ComponentFactory<any> {
    let cmpClass;
    let decoratedCmp;
    if (componentClass) {
      cmpClass = componentClass;
      decoratedCmp = Component(metadata)(cmpClass);
    } else {
      @Component(metadata)
      class RuntimeComponent {
        @Input() line: any;
        @Output() selectPhrase: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
        showEntities(lineIndex, entityIndex) {
          this.selectPhrase.emit(entityIndex);
        }
      };
      decoratedCmp = RuntimeComponent;
    }

    @NgModule({ imports: [CommonModule], declarations: [decoratedCmp] })
    class RuntimeComponentModule { }

    let module: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any> = compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(RuntimeComponentModule);
    return module.componentFactories.find(f => f.componentType === decoratedCmp);
  }
```

- and I display a text inside theis div based on the data I calculate and it's a string with html tags like that:

  Data My name is foo

  - I trigger the blur event of the div that is contenteditable and I see the changes and based on that I generate a new string with new spans and render it again the same div
  - the problem comes when I delete all the text from the contenteditable div the component removed from the dom and can't be reinstantiated again even if I try to type again in the field but it just type inside the div not the created component

how I can solve this problem and can generate the component when the user delete all text from field and try to type again ?

Here is a stackblitz for the project : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-stack?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Refer this link for dynamically creating a component. https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d

Comment: I know this link so well and I read it a lot and the other articles in dynamic component creation in angular but no one of them help me in this situation

Comment: instead of createComponentFactorySync()? can you create a component class and use 'componentFactoryResolver' injectable service to get the component factory?

Comment: You will likely to get quicker and better answer if can spare sometime to create demo app stackblitz.

Comment: Here is the stackblitz link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-stack?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution is by handling keystrokes in the contenteditable div especially the DEL , BackSpace Strokes so when the input is empty and the stroke is one of them you just create a new component , It still has problems that dynamic components is not appearing when have it's empty or have only a tag but that's the workaround that I came up with untill now